# Api retorna os dados corretamente pelo artisan serve mas não pelo apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Fiz uma api REST, utilizando o **Laravel**, para um aplicativo que estou fazendo , para realizar os testes de requisições criei uma VM onde está a api.

Atribui um ip fixo a esta VM e desativei o firewall para não incomodar.

Configurei assim:

Em `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apiTeste/public
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/apiTeste">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Em `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ouvidoria
127.0.0.1   api.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Realizando teste dentro da VM mesmo, se utilizo `http://api.dev` este retorna a página inicial do Laravel, mas se utilizo `http://api.dev/api/unidades` este retorna um `404 Not Found`:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /api/unidades was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) Server at api.dev Port 80
```

Porém se rodo o `php artisan serve` e acesso `http://api.dev:8000/api/unidades` este retorna os dados corretamente.

Comment: O mod_rewrite  do apache está habilitado?

Comment: Obrigado @AdrianodeAzevedo, pesquisei aqui sobre habilitar o mod_rewrite e após executar o procedimento funcionou

Comment: @AdrianodeAzevedo se quiser formalizar a resposta, senão depois irei colocar uma

Comment: Vou acrescentar uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Laravel utiliza o conceito de rotas para você conseguir acessar sua aplicação.

Verifique se a extensão **mod_rewrite** do apache está habilitado.

```
<?php
// teste.php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

Se verificar que a função não está definida é porque a extensão não está habilitada no Apache.

Então, vamos precisar habilitar o módulo do apache usando o comando **a2enmod**. No terminal digite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Feito isso, reinicie seu apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```