# Api retorna os dados corretamente quendo requisitada pelo localhost mas não pelo ip

Tags: apache, ubuntu, back-end

Ontem fiz [está pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255089/api-retorna-os-dados-corretamente-pelo-artisan-serve-mas-n%C3%A3o-pelo-apache):

> Fiz uma api REST, utilizando o **Laravel**, para um aplicativo que
>   estou fazendo , para realizar os testes de requisições criei uma VM
>   onde está a api.
>
> Atribui um ip fixo a esta VM e desativei o firewall para não
>   incomodar.
>
> Configurei assim:
>
> Em `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>
>   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
>
>   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName api.dev
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apiTeste/public
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <Directory "/var/www/html/apiTeste">
>   AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
>
> # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
> ```
>
> Em `/etc/hosts`:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.1.1 ouvidoria
> 127.0.0.1 api.dev
>
> # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
> ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
> fe00::0 ip6-localnet
> ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
> ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
> ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
> ```
>
> Realizando teste dentro da VM mesmo, se utilizo `http://api.dev` este
>   retorna a página inicial do Laravel, mas se utilizo
>   `http://api.dev/api/unidades` este retorna um `404 Not Found`:
>
> ```
> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /api/unidades was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) Server at api.dev Port 80
> ```
>
> Porém se rodo o `php artisan serve` e acesso
>   `http://api.dev:8000/api/unidades` este retorna os dados corretamente.

Através da resposta do consegui resolver o problema que tinha no momento, e consigo realizar a requisição com o serviço rodando no apache, mas apenas se eu executar esta requisição dentro da VM.

Caso tente acessar de fora da VM, ao entrar com o endereço `http://192.168.0.23/` retorna a página `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` como deveria ser.

Acessando `http://192.168.0.23/apiTeste/public/` me exibe a página inicial do `Laravel`.

Mas se entro com o endereço da requisição `http://192.168.0.23/api/unidades` este me retorna um erro de `404 Not Found`:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /api/unidades was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.23 Port 80
```

Comment: Como vc sobe a VM? Usando Vagrant + Virtualbox, só VB, ... ?

Comment: Uso só o virtualbox

Comment: Vai na propriedades da sua VM, vai na aba network, tem um Adapter 1 como NAT nao tem? 
Cria outro, adpater 2 como Bridge Adapter com Prmiscuoues Mode Allow All.

Tenta isso e veja se resolve

Comment: @RBoschini o adapter 1 ta em bridge com o ip setado manualmente

Comment: Tando que consigo acessar o apache, caso em nat não conseguiria

Comment: Não consegui descobrir o erro desta, mas iniciei uma nova do zero e está funcionou perfeitamente